# C# Database Application - Saving a list of values

Tags: c#, ms-access

this is my first question.

I'm making a small customer management program for a removals company and I've hit a bit of a snag.  At present, the program simply records customer information such as their name, their address and where they are moving to and this was fairly simple to implement but I've now come up against a bit of a problem that I'm hoping someone can help me with.

Basically my friend has asked me to take an excel spreadsheet has a list of common household items and their sizes in cubic feet.  This allows him to estimate how much room he needs in the truck and how many trucks he'll need for the job.  I thought this would be simple enough to implement, (And it probably is), but I'm just stuck trying to figure this out.

My plan was to move all of the items into a list in the program which could be added and removed and it would do the Cubic Feet calculation in the order but I just cannot for the life of me fathom how I'm going to save this information in the database, or rather save it in the appropriate row in the database.

Any ideas or suggestions on how something like this might be achieved? While I'm not a bad programmer my experience with databases and data handling are fairly limited so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Ian

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a `RemovalAssignment`-table or similar

```
RemovalAssignment
-----------------
AssignmentId int PK (Autoincrement)
CustomerId   int (FK -> Customer.CustomerId)
```

Then you create a table

```
CommonItem
----------
CommonItemId int PK (Autoincrement)
ItemName     nvarchar (unique)
Volume       numeric
```

Then you have a mapping table between `CommonItem` and `RemovalAssignment`

```
AssignmentItem
--------------
AssignmentId int PK (FK -> RemovalAssignment.AssignmentId)
CommonItemId int PK (FK -> CommonItem.CommonItemId)
Quantity     int
```

Use the `CommonItem` table to populate the list in your UI and add a row in the `AssignmentItem` table for storing how many of each item that is required for each Assignment.

(PK = Primary key)

Comment: Hi,Thanks, that's helped me out a lot. I've finally got it working.